# How to fill multiple backgrounds in a SVG object?

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to convert HTML element to SVG object. I have almost done it, except one thing:
I can't define multiple backgrounds in SVG because I don't know how to convert this

```
background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(177, 83%, 28%, 0.5),hsla(177, 83%, 28%, 0.6)), url(http://s23.postimg.org/5osuy1fpj/diagonal_noise.png);
```

for a svg object;

Here is a [codepen link](http://codepen.io/meanyack/pen/IrqEl)

Can anyone help me to fill a svg object with two backgrounds (image + gradient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.  You just need to add a `<rect>`, into your `<pattern>`, just before the `<image>`.  Set the fill of the `<rect>` to a `linearGradient` that you will need to also define.

You will also need to add an `opacity="0.6"` to your image.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a standard SVG gradient fill. All SVG rendering engines must recognize and render it correctly. No image fallback needed.